# Windows: How do I calculate the time it takes a c/c++ application to run?

Tags: c++, c, windows, testing, runtime

I am doing a performance comparison test. I want to record the run time for my c++ test application and compare it under different circumstances. The two cases to be compare are: 1) a file system driver is installed and active and 2) also when that same file system driver is not installed and active.

A series of tests will be conducted on several operating systems and the two runs described above will be done for each operating system and it's setup. Results will only be compared between the two cases for a given operating system and setup.

I understand that when running a c/c++ application within an operating system that is not a real-time system there is no way to get the real time it took for the application to run. I don't think this is a big concern as long as the test application runs for a fairly long period of time, therefore making the scheduling, priorities, switching, etc of the CPU negligible.

Edited: For Windows platform only
How can I generate some accurate application run time results within my test application?

Comment: "there is no way to get the real time it took for the application to run"  What does this mean?  What is this 'real' time that you cannot get?  The elapsed time seems real to me.

Comment: Real-time would be the actual time it took processing the code in the program. An OS that is not Real-Time manages processes and switching which processes will run at which times based on priorities and such. The whole time the application takes to run is usually greater than the time the application is actually processing because the OS switching between processes and your application is in a wait state for a little here and little there.

Comment: @Brian T Hannan: It is possible (even on a non-real-time OS) to measure both wall clock time and CPU time of a process.

Comment: The `time` command gives you both wall clock and CPU times.

Comment: What is wall clock time?

Comment: @Brian: "wall clock time" is the time of day according to your computer.  When you look at the clock in the Windows system tray, you're looking at wall clock time.

Comment: Pet peeve: you want to *measure* the running time, not *calculate* it which immediately puts me in mind of the halting problem...

Comment: @dmckee: Well you are right and you are wrong all at the same time. I do actually want to calculate it, but that's only because there is no way to measure it. In order to get the measurement I need to calculate the difference between the time the program ended and started. If there was a way to simply check the value of the run time then it would be measuring. Measuring is like when you use a ruler you put the tool to work and simply read the value. There is no such "ruler" as far as I can within Windows to do this.

Comment: @Brian: I'm a physicist. In my world having a little math in the analysis does not make a measurement into a calculation. Even with a ruler you have to note the starting point.

Comment: Pet peeve: guys who claim they have pet peeves about something irrelevant of the topic at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this

```
#if _DEBUG
time_t start = time(NULL);
#endif
```

and finish with this

```
#if _DEBUG
time end = time(NULL);
#endif
```

in your `int main()` method.  Naturally you'll have to return the difference either to a log or `cout` it.

Comment: Although some of the other solutions may have been robust, this was the most simple one and it is the one I ended up using and it seems to be working as far as I can tell.

Comment: @eSKay in seconds.  It can not time anything more accurately than that I'm afraid.  However, for most applications it gets the job done.

Answer (score 5):

If you're on a POSIX system you can use the `time` command, which will give you the total "wall clock" time as well as the actual CPU times (user and system).

Edit: Apparently there's an equivalent for Windows systems in the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en) called `timeit.exe` (not verified).

Comment: Yes, timeit.exe is the best way to do this on a Windows system, though cygwin probably gives you the unix 'time' command.

Comment: I see instances of both on Google, but I have no way to verify.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking is "How do I measure the time it takes for the process to run, irrespective of the 'external' factors, such as other programs running on the system?"  In that case, the easiest thing would be to run the program multiple times, and get an average time.  This way you can have a more meaningful comparison, hoping that various random things that the OS spends the CPU time on will average out.  If you want to get real fancy, you can use a statistical test, such as the two-sample t-test, to see if the difference in your average timings is actually significant.

Comment: Nice answer, I took statistics and it's a good idea but I think it might be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on ezod's answer.
You run the program with the time command to get the total time - there are no changes to your program

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Windows system you can use the high-performance counters by calling [QueryPerformanceCounter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li = {0}, li2 = {0};
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
    __int64 freq = li.QuadPart;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
        // run your app here...
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li2);

    __int64 ticks = li2.QuadPart-li.QuadPart;
    cout << "Reference Implementation Ran In " << ticks << " ticks" << " (" << format_elapsed((double)ticks/(double)freq) << ")" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

...and just as a bonus, here's a function that converts the elapsed time (in seconds, floating point) to a descriptive string:

```
std::string format_elapsed(double d) 
{
    char buf[256] = {0};

    if( d < 0.00000001 )
    {
        // show in ps with 4 digits
        sprintf(buf, "%0.4f ps", d * 1000000000000.0);
    }
    else if( d < 0.00001 )
    {
        // show in ns
        sprintf(buf, "%0.0f ns", d * 1000000000.0);
    }
    else if( d < 0.001 )
    {
        // show in us
        sprintf(buf, "%0.0f us", d * 1000000.0);
    }
    else if( d < 0.1 )
    {
        // show in ms
        sprintf(buf, "%0.0f ms", d * 1000.0);
    }
    else if( d <= 60.0 )
    {
        // show in seconds
        sprintf(buf, "%0.2f s", d);
    }
    else if( d < 3600.0 )
    {
        // show in min:sec
        sprintf(buf, "%01.0f:%02.2f", floor(d/60.0), fmod(d,60.0));
    }
    // show in h:min:sec
    else 
        sprintf(buf, "%01.0f:%02.0f:%02.2f", floor(d/3600.0), floor(fmod(d,3600.0)/60.0), fmod(d,60.0));

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I need high precision and there appears to be different types of output on various systems. Although this is a good suggestion, I think it's a bit much for what I'm doing.

Comment: @Brian: Perhaps not, just be aware that the granularity of GetTickCount() is not what it may seem.  The docs say it returns a value in milliseconds - but what they don't say is that the granularity of that value is perhaps several hundred milliseconds.  For a long-running program (ie > 1 second or so) this becomes a non-issue, but for timing code blocks GetTickCount() is worthless.

Comment: Correct, I will be timing the task of finding, opening, and reading x amount of characters from all the files within a specified directory path. The run times will be seconds and probably even minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and run your program by passing it as an argument to the *time* command.  When you're done, spend some time to learn the rest of the Unix tools that come with Cygwin.  This will be one of the best investments for your career you'll ever make; the Unix toolchest is a timeless classic.

Comment: That's a good idea, but would I have to install Cygwin on each test system I setup? I don't want to have to install anything on the test machines.

Comment: You could copy a minimal installation of cygwin on a USB stick.

Comment: About how long does it take to install? I will be repeating this test over and over again on machines that will be re-ghosted from ghost images. I will be running tests on various Windows OS's and don't want to waste time installing this thing time and time again.

Comment: I was suggesting to put a ready to run installation on the USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

QueryPerformanceCounter can have problems on multicore systems, so I prefer to use timeGetTime() which gives the result in milliseconds

you need a 'timeBeginPeriod(1)' before and 'timeEndPeriod(1)' afterwards to reduce the granularity as far as you can but I find it works nicely for my purposes (regulating timesteps in games), so it should be okay for benchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the program *very sleepy* to get a bunch of runtime information about your program.  Here's a link:  http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy